# Should a DACPAC (for a DB) create a server login?

Tags: sql-server-data-tools, dacpac

I just created a new DACPAC project and imported a DB. A file was created with these contents:

```
CREATE LOGIN [Processing]
    WITH PASSWORD = N'adsf&^*lajdf', SID = 0x..., DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = [us_english], CHECK_POLICY = OFF;
```

Should a DACPAC create a **server** login? A teammate suggested that this file be deleted, but I don't want to do that if it should remain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is a bit unclear, however I'll try to answer. DACPAC has everything, it will contain all database objects as well as logins and users, however you can control what exactly should you deploy by setting all needed settings via publish profiles.

Another point is that handling users and logins with SSDT is usually bad/complex idea mainly because you have different environments with different sets of users, their permissions and so on. So if you are not going to maintain users and logins via project then I agree with your teammate that it should be deleted from the project.

So, basically you need to ask yourself why do you want to have this user/login in the project.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I deleted the file that creates the login and now the DACPAC won't build. One advantage of creating the login would be new developer setup. Perhaps it's safe to just leave it? We'll have the login created already in our environments. I'm assuming the login creation, with the DACPAC, wouldn't harm anything if it already exists.

Comment: If the DACPAC is failing, then probably there is some reference to that user used in the code. Will that user use the password? Then the password will be simply stored to the source control. Other question will you have the same user on ALL environments you are going to deploy dacpac? And most probably the biggest question: will you store ALL logins to the SSDT and maintain all logins from the project? If no, then you'll be in troubles.